# Хандлер команд только при упоминании

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

У меня есть несколько ботов. И когда они находятся в одном чате, они конфликтуют между собой. То есть на команду `/start` отзывается сразу несколько ботов. Я бы хотел, чтобы бот отвечал на команду только при его упоминании (`/start@exapmle_bot`). Либо, если это невозможно, хотя бы чтобы при использовании `/start@exaple_bo`t не активировался `@example1_bot`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это возможно. Вам необходимо заглянуть в документацию по используемой библиотеке.

Comment: ну я же наверное посмотрел примеры кода перед тем, как написать вопрос

Comment: Примеры кода и документация - как мне кажется, разные вещи.